# C# Networkstream BeginRead How to obtain buffer length/size?

Tags: c#, networkstream

I have a problem to obtain the right buffer size of my application.
What i read from the site about specifying the buffer size is normally declared before reading.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];
```

And then using  to get the result.
However, this method will stop once the received data contains '00', but my return code contains something like this... 5300000002000000EF0000000A00. and the length is not fixed, can be this short until 400 bytes

So the problems comes, if i define a prefixed length like above, eg 2000, the return value is 
5300000002000000EF0000000A000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.......... 
thus making me unable to split the bytes to the correct amount.

Can any1 show me how to obtain the actual received data size from networkstream or any method/cheat to get what i need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have.

Comment: basically nothing i can show here, as i am stuck and cannot proceed at all. the only thing that i write and related to this topic is

    `tcpstream.BeginRead(readbuffer, 0, (int)tcpsocket.ReceiveBufferSize, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), tcpstream);`

and i am stuck at ReceiveCallBack method, coz totally cannot process the incoming data

Comment: `NetworkStream` inherits `Stream`, so `Stream.Length` will contain the length of the stream if known.

Comment: this is tried. it returns seek is not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network streams have no length.

Unfortunately, your question is light on detail, so it's hard to offer specific advice. But you have a couple of options:

- If the high-level protocol being used here offers a way to know the length of the data that will be sent, use that. This could be as simple as the remote host sending the byte count before the rest of the data, or some command you could send to the remote host to query the length of the data. Without knowing what high-level protocol you're using, it's not possible to say whether this is even an option or not.
- Write the incoming data into a MemoryStream object. This would always work, whether or not the high-level protocol offers a way to know in advance how much data to expect. Note that if it doesn't, then you will simply have to receive data until the end of the network stream.

The latter option looks something like this:

```
MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
int readByteCount;
byte[] rgb = new byte[1024]; // can be any size

while ((readByteCount = inputStream.Read(rgb, 0, rgb.Length)) > 0)
{
    outputStream.Write(rgb, 0, readByteCount);
}

return outputStream.ToArray();
```

This assumes you have a network stream named "inputStream".

I show the above mainly because it illustrates the more general practice of reading from a network stream in pieces and then storing the result elsewhere. Also, it is easily adapted to directly reading from a socket instance (you didn't mention what you're actually using for network I/O).

However, if you are actually using a Stream object for your network I/O, then as of .NET 4.0, there has been a more convenient way to write the above:

```
MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream);

return outputStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation and answer. it works for in my program. 
and there is a need to add a `break;` inside the while loop, or else it will be infinite.
Not able to test the simpler code due to my program is running in .net framework 3.5, due to compatibility with other hardware.

Comment: An infinite loop is odd. What condition to you use to control the execution of the `break` statement? It might be better to incorporate that information at a higher level, depending on what it is.

Comment: i use the code just as you write, especially the part to get the number of incoming data.

since you put `while(... > 0)`, if inputStream.Read contains data, it will be >0, thus it will forever stuck in the while loop. So adding a `break;` will quit the while loop after getting data.

Comment: Sorry, you're not making sense. If you added a `break` statement to the code, then you didn't use the code "just as you [I] wrote". And the test for `> 0` is a critical element of that code because you _want_ the loop to continue as long as data has been read. Please re-read my answer, especially the part where I point out that of the two broad suggestions I offered, one or the other but not both may be appropriate.